# Getting 404 error while running startsonar.bat on windows 11

Tags: java, elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I ran the sartsonar.bat file in cmd window I got the below error.

```
Starting SonarQube...
09:29:55.707 [main] WARN org.sonar.application.config.AppSettingsLoaderImpl - Configuration file not found: C:\sonarqube\conf\sonar.properties
2023.07.19 09:29:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube\temp
2023.07.19 09:29:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:50044]
2023.07.19 09:29:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [C:\sonarqube\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube\temp\conf\es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp C:\sonarqube\elasticsearch\lib\*;C:\sonarqube\elasticsearch\lib\cli-launcher\* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2023.07.19 09:29:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.07.19 09:29:56 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:151)
        at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:64)
        at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:92)
        at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:77)
        at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:62)
        at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:223)
        at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:288)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

I tried sonarqube 9.9, 10 and latest versions I got same error.
I used jdk-17, jdk1.8.0_212.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.